# How to make the table header bold with Knitr (for pdf output)?

Tags: r, knitr

How can I make the header bold when using `knitr::kable()` function? It is automatically formatted as bold in HTML or word output, however, I couldn't change the format of the header when pdf output is selected.

**Sample Code:**

```
library(knitr)
kable(head(iris))
```

**Output:**

[Image - The table header in pdf is not bold.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pzJJ.png)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `kableExtra` and format the table header with bold text.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(iris),format="latex") %>% row_spec(0,bold=TRUE) %>% 
kable_styling()
```

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any idea why the bold is gone after full_width = TRUE in kable_styling()?

Comment: Hello @Jane, I am not able to reproduce the problem you describe. `kable(head(iris),format="latex") %>% row_spec(0,bold=TRUE) %>% 
     kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)` produces a bold table heading for me.

Comment: Thanks @LenGreski for your reply - I use the exact same code but cannot get bold heading. I tried both the dev version and the CRAN version (1.1.0) on Windows 10, newest versions of R and RStudio. All other specifications (i.e. font_size, hline_after) work. Maybe I'll search up the issues on Github.

Comment: @Jane - do you obtain bold type in the heading when you exclude the `full_width=TRUE` argument from `kable_styling()`?

Comment: Hi @Len, I do get the bold font after I remove `full_width=TRUE`. I do need the full_width argument, so I tried the Latex method of doing so and succeeded, please refer to [my GitHub Issue](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/363)

Comment: @Jane This is coming over two years later, but `full_width = TRUE` is an argument, which exclusively pertains to HTML tables.